# USB Boot Error--Mac

Tags: boot, usb, mac, macbook

When booting Ubuntu 14.04.1 from a 16GB USB on a Macbook Pro 13", early 2011, a black screen shows up suggesting that a version 2.x beta is the version running on my machine.

I performed a flawless step-by-step install onto the USB as dictated [here](http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-drive-for-mac-in-os-x--cms-21253).

Whenever I choose "Try Ubuntu" or "Install Ubuntu" the screen goes black and never progresses.

What could cause this?